# Frame ticks not magnified along with plot

Tags: graphics, export, image, magnification, png-format

I am using *Mathematica* 11.0 under Linux.

I want to export some plots in PNG format, with resolution higher than the notebook display resolution.

When I evaluate

```
Export["filename.png", Magnify[plot, 2],"PNG"]
```

this gives me a good resolution, but the frame ticks from the plots are gone after magnification. I want the output in PNG format as I might need this figures later to assemble with other existing figures as an inset.

Is there a smarter way to improve the image resolution?

I have tried increasing `ImageSize`, but it does not help. Also, I have tried setting `ImageResoltion` up to 2500, but that does not help either.

#### Update

When I make a plot (say a list plot), I always use `Frame-> True` and `FrameTicks -> Automatic`. The frame ticks are visible when I export the plot as PNG without any magnification. However, the frame ticks are not visible when I use

```
Export["filename.png", Magnify[plot, 2],"PNG"]
```

Comment: I have no issues with your code.

Comment: I know that you do not have issues with my code, but that is not my question.

Comment: In that case I have no idea what is your question. You say "frame ticks are gone", but I don't replicate this.

Comment: When I make a plot (say ListPlot), I always use "Frame-> True" and "FrameTicks-> Automatic". These FrameTicks are visible if you export the plot as "PNG" without any magnification. However, the frame ticks are not visible when I use `Export["filename.png", Magnify[plot, 2],"PNG"]`

Comment: No, sorry. I don't have any issues with exporting either the normal plot, or the magnified: the ticks are on both.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because with the information provided the issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: I don't know but I have these issues. I am using Mathematica 11.0. I don't know what version are you using. But, your comments are not helping at all. I would not have taken the pain to post my question here if everything was working fine.

Comment: It would be helpful if you had taken the pain to state at the very beginning the version _you_ are using. V11 is known to have many issues, and the responsibility of the poster is to provide all the information required to reproduce the problem he/she is having.

Comment: I am sorry if this information was skipped, but the main reason for it was that I didnt think the version is a big problem. Anyways, do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: As a side note (off topic for the OP here, but relevant in general question posting policy): I raised this issue [on Meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/should-indicating-the-version-of-mma-be-compulsory), where I claim that stating the version should be compulsory in order to avoid such misunderstandings. And for the record: I'm using v10.4.1 (mainly because v11 has issues that I don't want to struggle with).

Comment: I don't see the issue. `plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic]; Export["filename.png", 
 Magnify[plot, 2], "PNG"]` gives me the same plot in png (with frames). Mac OS 10.12 Mma 11.0.1

Comment: @corey979: Thanks for raising this issue. I hope this will be beneficial for the question posting policy but I guess we are way off-track from my main question. Kindly refrain to go off-topic and comment only if you think your answer can be helpful to the poster.

Comment: @bill s: Thanks a lot for trying it. I think Mathematica Linux version might have these issues. But wait, you see the frames right ? Do you see the frame ticks too ?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is real, but has nothing to do with `Export`. It is a problem with `Magnification` alone. Running V11.0.1 on OS X, I can reproduce the problem in my note book as follows:

```
 plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True]
```

Then

```
 Style[plot, Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: screen]

The frame ticks are not magnified along with the rest of plot. I consider this a bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot; Yes, I guess its a magnification issue. However, in my case I do not see frame ticks at all (after exporting the magnified image) when I open the "PNG" in softwares like "gwenview". Anyways, the problem still persists. I need a high resolution plots in "PNG", which seems like an impossible task with Linux supporting Mathematica 11.0.